# Using the first tag of a photopost as a title - tumblr

Tags: post, tags, css-selectors, tumblr, photo

I'm trying to use the first tag of every photo/photoset post on tumblr specifically to style it as a title (text posts have built in title options, photo posts don't)
I found other - too handmade - solutions, but i think in the long run, the first tag would be a coherent way to do this.

I couldn't find out how to get only the first-child of the tag list, or get it from an array.

Is this possible?

thanks

Comment: It is possible using css alone, but you need to share your code or showing a working example for others to be able to help you.

Comment: i didn't find working examples...

Comment: You have answered your own question?

Comment: What about this: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/Lrkezh4n/ this simply uses a pure css solution.

Comment: @lharby i answered, because what i finally tried out, worked. i thought i post it here, so other people can use it too.(i dont know why this title problem even exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a pure css solution.

HTML:

```
<div class="post cf">
  <ul class="notes">
     <li>Note 1</li>
     <li>Note 2</li>
     <li>Note 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.notes {
  margin:0;
  list-style:none;
}

.notes li {
  float:left;
  padding-right:10px;
}

.notes li:first-child {
  float:none;
  color:red;
  font-size:2em;
}
```

You haven't provided any html, so I have guessed at the structure, but the principle can be easily applied.

Also if you only want this to affect photo posts, you can easily change the css selector to

```
.photo .notes li:first-child { //css }
```

etc.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/Lrkezh4n/)

Answer (score 0):

directly after the {photo} section beginning in the tumblr source editor, i wrote this little js. i placed the same after my {photoset} tag.
So now my first tags of photo and photoset posts are acting as titles.
this goes to the head section

```
.tag_to_title { STYLE HERE }
```

and the bellow snippet {photo} HERE in the beginning {/photo} and {photoset} HERE as well {/photoset}

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myTags = {};
    {block:Posts}
    {block:HasTags}
    myTags[{JSPostID}] = [
        {block:Tags}
        {
            "tag": {JSTag},
            "tagURL": {JSTagURL},
        },
        {/block:Tags}
    ];
    </script>
    <h2 class="tag_to_title">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(myTags[{JSPostID}][0].tag);
    </script>
    </h2>
    </br>
    {/block:HasTags}
    {/block:Posts}
```